# How ARIN IP Address is used in APNIC Region?

Tags: routing, ipv4, ip-address

Amazon AWS provides the following JSON ([Source](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json)) which has list of IP Address ranges used by AWS.

```
    {
      "ip_prefix": "54.179.0.0/16",
      "region": "ap-southeast-1",
      "service": "EC2"
    }
```

The IP address range **54.179.0.0/12** belongs to ARIN (ASN - **AS16509**).

https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-54-176-0-0-1

But the JSON says that the CIDR **54.179.0.0/16** is used by EC2 in Asia Pacific South East 1 region.

Here are my questions:

1. How can the IP belongs to ARIN used in APNIC region?
2. How IP address belongs to one ASN can be used across different geolocations? how the routing works here?

Comment: You should ask ARIN these questions, they have a perfectly good support.

Answer (score 2):

The RIRs dish out the IP addresses, but they don’t get involved in the advertisement of the addresses.  If I were to request some addresses from RIPE in the UK and I purchased a dark fibre to the USA and peered directly with a Tier 1 in the USA, the addresses would be advertised through America, but would be RIPE IPs.  It would appear as though the addresses were USA based from a routing perspective.